# Describe the algorithm to swap two adjacent elements by adjusting only the links (and not the data) using: a, singling link list b, doubling link list

Tags: java, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

I like anyone help me explaining the question more detail because I am very confused with the question. I'm not sure what adjacent element meant. Does the question ask me to describe both singling and doubling? singling link contain data and next referent to the next node that running as a linear. Doubling link has data, next and previous which make it easy to go back to the previous node and next node. I'm not sure if doubling run as linear or what coz I know it can used in the binary tree which has two routes. I just need hints. thank you.

Comment: What are you really asking?'

Comment: the tittle is the question. I don't even know how to answer that question. that's why I am here.

Comment: Two elements `A` and `B` are adjacent (in the case of singly-linked lists) if there is a link from `A` to `B`, or if there is a link from `B` to `A`. In the case of doubly-linked lists, there would be links from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Singly Linked List
   A-->B-->C-->D-->E
   I think {A ,B},{B,C},{C,D},{D,E} are the adjacent elements
   Algorithm

   list=head;

   ```
   While(list->next!=null)
   ```

   {

   temp=list->next;

   ```
   list->next=temp->next;

   temp->next=list;

   list=list->next;
   ```

}

.
 2. Doubly linked list
A<-->B<-->C<-->D<-->E
I think {A ,B},{B,C},{C,D},{D,E} are the adjacent elements.